# setting up Jira on MySQL 8 with docker

Tags: mysql, docker, jira

I'm trying to set up jira on an existing MySQL database using a docker environment.
Both mysql and jira were created as containers with the corresponding images from docker-hub.

The Jira instance recognizes the connection to MySQL.
Unfortunately an error is thrown

[Jira config error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMZSw.png)

The provided link goes to https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/connecting-jira-applications-to-mysql-5-7-966063305.html

In order to use the proper mysql driver I mapped the java mysql-connection-driver for the used mysql-verison into the jira container under

`/opt/atlassian/jira/lib/`

[Jira mysql-connectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHUD0.png)
The 5th version comes with the image.

But I cannot delete the 5th version of the connector to make sure the 8th version is used. It always throws permission erros. Either when trying directly inside the container as well as using a docker command from the host. Currently I cannot confirm which driver is used.
Furthermore there is no bin-version available after downloading the latest connector from mysql.

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

MySQL version: 8.0.15

The MySQL container is running and available. The database was created via phpmyadmin.
I created a link from the host to set up additional custom configuration for MySQL under

`/etc/mysql/conf.d/my-override.cnf`

Following the instructions of the guide I added the config values to the cnf-file:

```
[mysqld]
default-storage-engine=INNODB
character_set_server=utf8mb4
innodb_default_row_format=DYNAMIC
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
#innodb_large_prefix=ON
#innodb_file_format=Barracuda
innodb_log_file_size=2G
```

As you can see, the `file_format` and `prefix` directives are commented because the container throws errors while starting that this variable is unknown.

What can I try that jira uses the database within the mysql-container?

Answer (score -3):

Jira does not support MySQL 8 yet...[Supported MySQL versions according to Atlassian documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rz80T.png),  [Source](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver072/supported-platforms-828787550.html).
You can always try to set your mysql server in 5.7 compatibility mode.....

Comment: This kind of answer is always better if you can include a citation.